# What is the best database schema to handle multiple login types when using passwords and smart cards?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have seen a lot of questions regarding multiple log in accounts (e.g Facebook, OAuth, Password etc) and how to handle these in database design, however, I am not sure how to best handle my requirements.

I have a table of "Users" who each could log into my back end system (web app), OR my end user win forms application.

When a User is registered, they may be provided a User Name and Password, or a Smart Card, or both.

Some users can then use their Smart Card to log into my back end system from their client desktop application, and users with the password can login online.

Now, if some users have both the password AND smart card ability, and some have only the password OR the smart card option.

Also, each user has a role (admin, user etc) AND a set of 1x or more Authentication codes (these are access codes that are used by the smart card login).

So I was thinking of using the following approach.

1. User table
2. Account table
3. Smart Card table
4. Password Table

User table holds the user info (name, email etc)

Account table links to the user table ad tells us what type of account they have, and also links to the smart card and password tables, so each user account could have one or more smart cards, and one or more passwords etc.

My issue with the above would mean that is a user has only a password, the entry for the smart card would be NULL etc. Is this OK?

Is there a better way to handle this?

At the end of the day, not all users will have all methods of log in, and some will, so I could not think of any design that would get away with NULL values somewhere in the tables.

Thank you